# В файл php не приходит запрос на wp, хотя add_action('wp_ajax_helloy содержит helloy и var data = { 'action': 'helloy', в js?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

В файл php не приходит запрос на wp, хотя add_action('wp_ajax_helloy содержит helloy и var data = { 'action': 'helloy', в js?

ajaxurl тоже ниже определён.

php фаил

```
<div class="ajax-load-relative-post" >
    <?php

    add_action('wp_ajax_helloy', 'helloy');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_helloy', 'helloy');

   function helloy(){
       allert("Получилось");
       wp_die();
       }
    ?>
    <?php
    function my_action_javascript() {
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript' id="true_loadmore">
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

JS файл

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var bottomOffset = 2000; // отступ от нижней границы сайта, до которого должен доскроллить пользователь, чтобы подгрузились новые посты
        var data = {
            'action': 'helloy',
            'name':'AAA'
        };
        if( $(document).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - bottomOffset) && !$('body').hasClass('loading')){
            $.ajax({
                url:ajaxurl,
                data:data,
                type:'POST',
                beforeSend: function( xhr){
                    $('body').addClass('loading');
                },
                success:function(data){
                    if( data ) {
                        $('#true_loadmore').before(data);
                        $('body').removeClass('loading');

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Тебе же дали мануал как подключать, а ты проигнорировал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/935919/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-ajax-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-php-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bb#comment1553865_935919

Comment: Когда я окажусь в аду, однажны, я буду знать что Энрико Такатти за его "view" вариться в котле где-то рядом.

Comment: Так вот по нему и сделал js работает php нет все подключил по инструкции

Comment: add_action('wp_ajax_helloy', 'helloy');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_helloy', 'helloy'); экшен заканчивается на helloy тоже содержит должно работать  var data = {
            'action': 'helloy',
            'name':'AAA'
        };

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не работает, потому что руководство по ajax на kama прочитано очень невнимательно.

Где wp_enqueue_script()?

Где wp_localize_script()? Функция my_action_javascript() содержит попытку выставить переменную ajaxurl, но эта функция не вызывается. Следовательно, ajax() в js коде будет делать вызов не пойми куда.

Что за функция allert()? Нет такой функции в wp, в результате получите ошибку 500. Надо делать вывод через echo.

Где вы видели в примерах ajax на kama использования wp_die()? Надо использовать просто die(), чтобы не было лишнего вывода.

Почему у вас add_action и helloy внутри html-блока? Они должны быть в functions.php, иначе не будут зарегистрированы.

На scroll вот так в лоб вешать нельзя, у вас будет вылетать пачка ajax запросов сразу. Нужно выставлять флаг до ajax и снимать его после. Если флаг установлен, не запускать ещё один ajax. Не забывайте, что это асинхронный вызов.

Устраните эти ошибки, пробуйте снова. Проверяйте сообщения в консоли браузера, коды ответа во вкладке network. Освойте отладку в WP (есть руководство на kama) или хотя бы пишите из helloy контрольные сообщения в файл, чтобы узнать, вызвалась ваша helloy или нет.